# Why is this Python Program not working as expected?

Tags: python

I was writing a simple python program in *pyCharm*, but this program is not working as expected!
The code is:

```
value= input("""Assign a whole number to x, such that 23< x >25:""")
if value==24:
    print("""Correct! Your are the next Bertrand Russell!!""" )
else:
    print("""Wrong. Try again!""")
```

But even if I assign the value 24 to x, I get

```
Wrong. Try again!
```

as output!

Is there any mistake in my understanding? Or is it just a *pyCharm* bug?

[image]

Comment: `input` always returns a string, which won't be equal to a number.

Comment: if value=="24":

Comment: Please post textual information as text, notvas a screenshot. Also choose a helpful title. Most questions here are about programs not working as expected.

Comment: @Klaus D I have posted textual information and screenshot, as well, for clarity. The title is helpful, at least to me, as it clearly indicates that the problem is related to python  and the problem is in unexpected result I am getting. Isnt it helpful?

Comment: @deceze thanks, now I can see where the problem is.